# What is the meaning of "big two hillbillies were blowing on them."?

Tags: meaning

In the comedy movie "*Little Nicky (2000)*", in hell, The Devil said these words to the Gatekeeper while playing cards. Actually, the Gatekeeper has breasts on top of the head.

> "Off with the brassiere. The last time I saw a pair of jugs that **big, two hillbillies were blowing on them**."

Comment: You have parsed it wrongly. Put a comma between big and two.   What meanings does "jugs" have? What is a hillbilly. Google "hillbilly blowing on jug"

Comment: @JamesK Make sure to turn Safe Search on first ;).

Comment: I actually checked, and google images is all pretty SFW even after several pages.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pun involving the ordinary sense of *jugs* designating ceramic or glass containers for liquids and the transferred sense of *jugs* designating breasts.

"Old-time" or "mountain" music, a style of North American folk music whose epicenter was the "hillbilly" rural communities of Appalachia, stereotypically involves a bass line produced by blowing across the mouth of a gallon jug:

> The jug used as a musical instrument is an empty jug (usually made of glass or stoneware) played with buzzed lips to produce a trombone-like tone. The characteristic sound of the jug is low and hoarse, below the higher pitch of the fiddle, harmonica, and the other instruments in the band.
>   —[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jug_(instrument))